# Regex expression in plain english

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on a new Java project and therefore im reading the already existing code. On a very important part of the code if found the following regex expression and i can't really tell what they are doing. Anybody can explain in plain english what they do??

1)

```
 [^,]*|.+(,).+
```

2)

```
(\()?\d+(?(1)\))
```

Comment: The second one doesn't compile in `Pattern`. Maybe missed a backslash? The `(?` part looks odd.

Comment: Agreed with the (?, looks very odd.  The question mark may escape the '(' without using a backslash.  That is the only way I can think it would work

Comment: Maybe it was supposed to be non-capturing '(?:'

Comment: @BalusC: it's conditionals, which isn't supported in Java. See my answer.

Comment: Was this project written in Java originally?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1)

```
[^,]* means any number of characters that are not a comma
.+(,).+ means 1 or more characters followed by a comma followed by 1 or more characters
|  means either the first one or the second one
```

2)

```
(\()? means zero or one '('  note* backslash is to escape '('
\d+ means 1 or more digits
(?(1)\)) means if back-reference \1 matched, then ')' note* no else is given
```

Also note that parenthesis are used to capture certain parts of the regular expression, except, of course, if they are escaped with a backslash

Comment: `(?` is if-then-else conditionals, which isn't supported by Java. See my answer.

Comment: A summary of the whole regular expression in English would also be useful.

Answer (score 17):

Next time you need a regex explained, you can use the following [`explain.pl`](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) service from Rick Measham:

```
Regex: [^,]*|.+(,).+

NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^,]*                    any character except: ',' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

---

```
Regex: (\()?\d+(?(1)\))

NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you're using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?(1)                    if back-reference \1 matched, then:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        else:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             succeed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of conditional on \1
```

#### Links

- http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl

---

#### Note on conditionals

JAVA DOES NOT SUPPORT CONDITIONALS! An unconditionalized regex for the second pattern would be something like:

```
\d+|\(\d+\)
```

i.e. a non-zero repetition of digits, with or without surrounding parentheses.

#### Links

- [regular-expressions.info/If-then-else conditionals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)

  > Conditionals are supported by the JGsoft engine, Perl, PCRE and the .NET framework.

---

#### The patterns in depth

Here's a test harness for the first pattern

```
    import java.util.regex.*;
    //...

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^,]*|.+(,).+");
    String[] tests = {
        "",       // [] is a match with no commas
        "abc",    // [abc] is a match with no commas
        ",abc",   // [,abc] is not a match
        "abc,",   // [abc,] is not a match
        "ab,c",   // [ab,c] is a match with separating comma
        "ab,c,",  // [ab,c,] is a match with separating comma
        ",",      // [,] is not a match
        ",,",     // [,,] is not a match
        ",,,",    // [,,,] is a match with separating comma
    };
    for (String test : tests) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
        System.out.format("[%s] is %s %n", test,
            !m.matches() ? "not a match"
            : m.group(1) != null
               ? "a match with separating comma"
               : "a match with no commas"
        );
    }
```

#### Conclusion

- To match, the string must fall into one of these two cases:

  - Contains no comma (potentially an empty string)
  - Contains a comma that separates two non-empty strings
- On a match, `\1` can be used to distinguish between the two cases

And here's a similar test harness for the second pattern, rewritten without using conditionals (which isn't supported by Java):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+|(\\()\\d+\\)");
    String[] tests = {
        "",       // [] is not a match
        "0",      // [0] is a match without parenthesis
        "(0)",    // [(0)] is a match with surrounding parenthesis
        "007",    // [007] is a match without parenthesis
        "(007)",  // [(007)] is a match with surrounding parenthesis
        "(007",   // [(007] is not a match
        "007)",   // [007)] is not a match
        "-1",     // [-1] is not a match
    };
    for (String test : tests) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
        System.out.format("[%s] is %s %n", test,
            !m.matches() ? "not a match"
            : m.group(1) != null
               ? "a match with surrounding parenthesis"
               : "a match without parenthesis"
        );
    }
```

As previously said, this matches a non-zero number of digits, possibly surrounded by parenthesis (and `\1` distinguishes between the two).

Comment: wow didn't know about that site. Looks great. How 'complex' can the program handle?

Comment: @ggfan: it's just mechanical translation. It's probably not that hard to cover all syntax. To machine, regex isn't all that "confusing".

Comment: If you're find yourself doing a lot of this kind of thing, you might want to invest in RegexBuddy.  It will tell you how (and whether) a regex works *in your language/flavor of choice*, not just in Perl (which supports a lot more features that Java doesn't). http://www.regexbuddy.com/

Answer (score -1):

1) Anything that doesn't starts with a comma, or anything that contains a comma in between.

2) Any number that ends with a 1, and is between parenthesis, possible closed before and opened again after the number.

Comment: @AlanMoore: What is this different from polygenelubricants conclusion, besides than this is not an tool-generated response?

Comment: 1) `[^,]*` is **not** "Anything that doesn't starts with a comma", which would be `[^,].*` (except for newline characters). Instead `[^,]*` is "anything not containing a comma". 2) As noted in other answers, the `(?(1)...)` part is a conditional expression (missing in Java), and not a grouped `1` character. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

Comment: @poly's answer also includes a thorough analysis of both regexes, which is very different from yours.  In particular, the first regex *will* match a string that starts with a comma if there's at least one more comma.  I suspect its purpose is to determine whether a string represents a single item or a comma-separated list of items.